# Node Redis Pub/Sub between parent and child process

Tags: redis, node-redis

I am trying to implement Pub/Sub between a parent process and a child process in Node.JS.

I am using node-redis version 4.6.7 and redis server version 6.2.12.

I have built a Connection object that has it's own module. It handles connecting to redis and then returns the connected client wrapped into a promise.

```
  if (isDev) {
      this.client = createClient({ url: config.REDIS_URL_DEV });
  } else {
      this.client = createClient({ url: config.REDIS_URL_PROD });
  }

  this.promisedClient = new Promise((resolve) => {
       this.client.connect().then(() => {
            resolve(this.client);
       });
  });
```

I require the Module both in the parent process and in the child process.

Inside the Child Process, I subscribe to the channel on which the parent sends the message:

```
const sub = c.duplicate();

sub.connect().then(() => {
    sub.subscribe('PuppeteerScraper::IN', (source) => { ... here goes my handler code ... })
})
```

Inside the parent, after I've made sure, the child process has subscribed, I publish a message:

```
    proc.stdout.on('data', data => {
        const decodedData = data.toString('utf8');

        if (decodedData === 'PuppeteerScraperWorker::Subscribed') {
            client.then(c => {
               c.publish('PuppeteerScraper::IN', JSON.stringify(source));
            })
        }
    })
```

The problem is, there is no error when the child subscribes, no error when the parent publishes. Finally, the data is not received by the child process.

When I turn on the profiler, I see the publish command, but not the subscribe command.

```
04:59:29.246 [0 192.168.1.209:24164] "PUBLISH" "PuppeteerScraper::IN" "{"scraper":"Puppeteer","url":"<redacted>"}"
```

Basically, the subscribe command from the child process doesn't show up in the profiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Turns out I didn't tell the child process to connect to dev and so the parent was talking to DEV and the child was talking to PROD.